# REST make sure transport is HTTPS?

Tags: java, rest, https, swagger

I have a Restful Web Service written in Java:

Example:

```
@GET
@PATH("/foo")
public Response getFoo(){
... 
}
```

and a filter

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
   ....
}
```

How can i make sure that incoming requests and sent responses from my REST API are transported by HTTPS?

Comment: I think you want to look at the <transport-guarantee> in web.xml

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncbk/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to `ServletRequest`, you can use `ServletRequest.isSecure` to determine whether it was HTTPS or not.

Be careful, if your application gets deployed behind some frontend servers that extract HTTPS for you, you have to do something different. Usually check some headers or similar.